# ImportError: cannot import name HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

Tags: python, ntlm

I am working on some python script  to download some file from some website and I facing

```
authentication issues HTTPError: 401;Unauthorized.
```

So i changed the HTTP AUTH handler to NTLM and written the following script

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = 'user'
password = "pwd"
url = "http://clientdownload.xxxx.com/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)

auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(response.read())
```

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ntlm.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
  File "ntlm.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler


ImportError: cannot import name HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.
```

I observed that my python doesnt have python-ntlm package so did

```
pip install python-ntlm
```

whereas it didnt worked even after installing.

I hope I am not installing in proper way.

please help me out with the proper pointers to sort out this issue.

thanks in advance,
venkat

Comment: Do you have any `HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py` file files beside you python script?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I received a 401 error for my computer time not being equivalent with the web server that I was connecting to.  I fixed it by running this command:

```
sudo ntpdate -s us.pool.ntp.org
```